# Find and remove int duplicates in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

First, I know there is a lot of duplicate answers already, but I can't find what I want, even searched in Google. This is a question asked in an interview.

So, for my question:
I have the next int array:

`int[] array = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9};`

**EDIT:** You can assume that the array is sorted.

I want to get only the distinct values, without the duplicates, meaning:

```
array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ......};
```

**EDIT:**  Assume that you don't need to shrink the array, but return the values in their sorted order, and the rest of the values at the end.

There is a couple of instructions:

1. Don't use any other or new array, meaning use the same array for returning the result.
2. Don't use any Collections like Set or ArrayList.
3. Make it the most useful you can.

Iv'e tried to do this with Set, but now I want something different.
Also tried to replace the duplicate values with -1 value, but this is true only when I'm assuming that I'm using positive values only.

If you find identical question, tell me and I will delete this one.

Thanks.

Comment: A set is what you need to create from that data - which is what the `Set` class is for. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Are we to assume the input array will always be sorted?

Comment: You can't shrink an array so I don't know how you intend to do that. Can you assume the values are sorted already?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski This what the interviewer asked. Believe me, I was not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Actually, a sentence like the one in the second line of code means that a new array is used. In many languages, in fact, the modification of the size of such an array implies the usage of a new one. What are, therefore, the specific limitations of alternative structure usage?

Comment: @OfirA. ok... your shrink function will still contain duplicates, but you can return the size of the subarray with no duplicate.

Comment: @broncoAbierto lets say that I don't need to shrink the array, but return the values in their distinct order, and the rest of the values in the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If they're in order, that's not terribly difficult.

```
/**
 * removes duplicates in the provided sorted array
 * @return the number of different elements (they're at the beginning)
 */
public static int shrink(int[] array) {
    int w = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
      if (i==0 || array[i]!=array[i-1]) {
          array[w++]=array[i];
      }
    }
    return w;
}
```

After that, only the first `w` elements are interesting.

Comment: I edited in order to try to implement also requirement 3 (be the most useful possible).

Comment: @dystroy I think you can avoid `i==0` in if statement if you write `if(array[i]!=array[i+1])`

Comment: @loler I don't think so. Test it with non duplicates at both ends.

Comment: @dystroy ok, i think then you have to avoid overload in case of last element.